# How to read a JSON returned Array

Tags: php, arrays, json

How do I read this array?

```
stdClass Object ( 
  [0] => stdClass Object ( 
    [role_id] => 1 
    [username] => me@gmail.com 
    [date_time] => 2013-01-13 14:01:00
  ) 
  [status] => success 
)
```

I can read the status as $objectname->status but I am not able to rwad $objectname->username.

Comment: try objectname[0].username

Comment: This is PHP, not JavaScript. Suggest to use `$objectname->{"0"}->username`.

Comment: WORKED. Thank you friend!

Comment: Wow, numeric properties .. didn't think I'd ever get to see it.

Comment: Jack - is there something wrong using it that way? Just curious

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because `username` is a property of `$objectname->{"0"}`, which is also an object.

Try this:

```
$json='{"0":{"role_id":1,"username":"me@gmail.com","date_time":"2013-01-13 14:01:00"},"status":"success"}';
$obj=json_decode($json);
var_dump($obj);
var_dump($obj->{"0"}->username);
```

[Live example](http://3v4l.org/fYCJ7)